# Getting all solutions to an equation on condition the variables are either 0 or 1

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

Given a list of 3-bit binary lists

```
b={{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{0,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}};
```

I would like to have all possible solutions to

```
s={0,1,0};
Mod[a[2] b[[2]] + a[3] b[[3]] + a[4] b[[4]] + ... + a[8] b[[8]], 2] = s
```

where each variable a[i] is either 0 or 1.

For instance;

```
Mod[{1,0,0} + {1,1,0},2]=={0,1,0}
```

for which a[5]=1 and a[7]=1 and all others 0.

Is this possible with Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW this can be solved by brute force:
e.g.

```
b = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
t = Tuples[{0, 1}, 8];
sol[s_] := Select[t, Mod[# . b, 2] == s &]
```

Solutions can be visualized:

```
Graph[ArrayPlot[sol[#]] -> ArrayPlot[{#}, ImageSize -> 50] & /@ b, 
 VertexSize -> 0, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]]
```

[image]

**Corrected answer as per comment**

```
b = IntegerDigits[Range@7, 2, 3];
t = IntegerDigits[Range@127, 2, 7];
ans[s_] := Select[t, Mod[# . b, 2] == s &]
Graph[ArrayPlot[ans[#], ImageSize -> 30] -> 
ArrayPlot[{#}, ImageSize -> 30] & /@ b, VertexSize -> 0,VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, `sol[s]` produces `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},...,{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}}`. Therefore, this is not it (The number of the unknowns equals 7, not 8.). Hope your answer may be  corrected. Good luck!

Comment: Also `Dimensions[sol[s]]` performs `{32, 8}`. One sees duplication.

Comment: You are strictly correct. As b[1] ={0,0,0} the duplication  you refer to is evident in array plot with first column0s then 1s. The point of my answer was that brute force can solve. If I get time I will constrain the answer to fit the question.

Comment: Sorry, your edited code `s = {0, 1, 0}; b = IntegerDigits[Range@7, 2, 3];
     t = IntegerDigits[Range@127, 2, 7];
     ans[s_] := Select[t, Mod[# . b, 2] == s &]
     Graph[ArrayPlot[ans[#], ImageSize - › 30] - ArrayPlot[{#), 
    ImageSize -> 30] & /@ b, VertexSize -> 0, 
 VertexLabels - *Placed["Name", Center]]` does not work at all: the one generates several syntax errors, e.g. "Syntax::bktmcp: Expression "{#" has no closing "}"."

Comment: Hopefully corrected now.

Comment: Unfortunately, still no:"ArrayPlot::argt: ArrayPlot called with 2 arguments; 0 or 1 arguments are expected." and abstraction as the output.

Comment: The code works. It has always worked. The issue is copy and pasting from iPhone OCR. This link is Mathematica online notebook image: you can edit (as is your penchant) or I will do later as I am going to work now.  https://imgur.com/a/7NOhEUe

Comment: Very nice, very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

An equivalent version to user64494's answer is the following:

```
    Solve[
        Mod[a . b[[2 ;;]], 2] == s && VectorLessEqual[{0, a, 1}] && a ∈ Vectors[7, Integers], 
        a
    ]
```

> {{a -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}}, {a -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}}, {a -> {0,
> 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}}, {a -> {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}}, {a -> {0, 1, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {a -> {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {a -> {0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
> 1, 0}}, {a -> {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}}, {a -> {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
> 0}}, {a -> {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}}, {a -> {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
> 0}}, {a -> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {a -> {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
> 1}}, {a -> {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}, {a -> {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
> 1}}, {a -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}}}

I should point out that here each vector corresponds to your `{a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]}`

Comment: For example, are the indices of `a -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}` OK? What is `a[3]`?

Comment: Excellent, I have Mathematica  11.3 so I will need a definition of VectorLessEqual as well, please.

Comment: Does the following work? `Solve[Mod[a . b[[2 ;;]], 2] == s && Max[a] <= 1 && Min[a] >= 0 && 
  a ∈ Vectors[7, Integers], a]`

Comment: I get errors: Vectors: --Message text not found --(z) and Solve: Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition a E Vectors[7,z]

Comment: I don't have 11.3 any more to check. How about `Solve[Mod[a . b[[2 ;;]], 2] == s && a ∈ RegionProduct @@ Table[Point[{{0}, {1}}], {7}], a]`

Comment: Yes, this works with 11.3 and is so elegant! Thank you Carl Woll.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as follows.

```
b = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0},{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
s = {0, 1, 0};
Reduce[Mod[Sum[a[k]*b[[k]], {k, 2, 8}], 2] == s && a[1] >= 0 && 
a[1] <= 1 && a[2] >= 0 && a[2] <= 1 && a[3] >= 0 && a[3] <= 1 && 
a[4] >= 0 && a[4] <= 1 && a[5] >= 0 && a[5] <= 1 && a[6] >= 0 && 
a[6] <= 1 && a[7] >= 0 && a[7] <= 1 && a[8] >= 0 && a[8] <= 1, 
Table[a[k], {k, 2, 8}], Integers]
```

> `(a[1] == 0 ||  a[1] == 1) && ((a[2] == 0 && a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 0 && a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 0 &&  a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 1 &&  a[8] == 0) || (a[2] == 0 && a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 1 && a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 0 &&  a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 0 &&  a[8] == 0) || (a[2] == 0 && a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 0 && a[8] == 0) || (a[2] == 0 &&  a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 1 &&  a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 0 && a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 1 && a[8] == 0) || (a[2] == 0 &&  a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 0 &&  a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 1 && a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 1 && a[8] == 0) || (a[2] == 1 &&  a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 0 &&  a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 1 && a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 0 && a[8] == 0) || (a[2] == 1 &&  a[3] == 0 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 1 &&  a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 1 && a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 1 && a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 1 &&  a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 0 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 0 &&  a[8] == 0) || (a[2] == 1 && a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 0 && a[6] == 1 && a[7] == 0 && a[8] == 1) || (a[2] == 1 &&  a[3] == 1 && a[4] == 1 && a[5] == 1 && a[6] == 0 && a[7] == 1 &&  a[8] == 0))`

Comment: Thank you, this works with v11.3